# Combine QtService and FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, qt, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a cloud messaging service in my qt android application. I use firebase api for this. But i am facing the following problem:

I want to receive notifications by using a service. In Qt in order to create a service you must set your java class to extends from `QtService`. But according to Firebase api in order to receive notifications java class must extends `FirebaseMessagingService`. This is very annoying because i can not create a service in Qt if i made my class inherits `FirebaseMessagingService` and also i can not receive notifications if inherits `QtService`.

Any idea how can i implement this?

I've already tried inner classes and interfaces but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to extend two or more classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233345/any-way-to-extend-two-or-more-classes-in-java)

Comment: I know that is not possible in java. I've already tried inner classes and interfaces but i had no luck. Any other idea?

Comment: I've run into the same problem with MediaBrowserServiceCompat. I need to extend my service from this class as well as from QtService. Have you found any solution?